# Invoking a function in MySQL returns no information rows

Tags: mysql, sql, function, self-invoking-function

Below is the function I created in MySQL. MySQL accepted it and created the function. When  go to invoke the function it gives me no error message, but returns no rows with info...it should though. What mistake am I making? I feel like it's the "INTO salary" line. The part after "END $$" is what I wrote to invoke the function. I want this function, when invoked, to give me the result as the avg salary of that company.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION high_pay1 (salary VARCHAR(20))
    RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    DECLARE salary INT;
    SELECT AVG(salary) INTO salary
    FROM works
    WHERE company_name= 'first bank corp';
RETURN salary;
END $$


SELECT salary, company_name
FROM works
WHERE high_pay1(salary) >'75000';
```

Comment: why is column salary VARCHAR(20). Wrong datatype?

Comment: you never use salary parameter in your function

Comment: Don't know what result AVG(string-value) is.

Comment: oh, see very new to mysql

Comment: so what exactly am i doing wrong, what parameter should i put in the (salary spot)

Comment: one more example you "RETURNS INT" but later you return salary with data type VARCHAR. Please check mysql manual again.

Comment: Please build a complete sample in sqlfiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/ )

Comment: I fixed that. what part am i missing

Comment: thats ok, i have loads of other stuff i have to do today, ill just come back to this later, or when someone else can contribute.